# In unity 2D c# how to rotate an object like geometry dash?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In [my game](https://youtu.be/6aGM5-7cNKc), my main character is a cube and if press space it's jumping depending on how much you press the button but I want to rotate my cube 90 degrees when pressing the space button. I am unsure of how to achieve this.

Here is what I am currently trying

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) 
{ 
    timeCount=Time.time 
} 

if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space)) 
{ 
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90), timeCount*.1f); 
    timeCount = 0; 
}
```

**Edit:** Here is my updated code with your code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerEverything : MonoBehaviour{
    public Transform GroundCheck; // Put the prefab of the ground here
    
    public LayerMask groundLayerBlue; // Insert the layer here.
    public LayerMask groundLayerPurple;
    public bool isGroundedBlue;   
    public bool isGroundedPurple;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2D;
    private float jumpTimer;
    private float timeCount = 0.0f;
    private bool isGrounded;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public LayerMask groundLayer;
    // we are going to store our coroutine to assure that it is only going to run once
    private Coroutine RotationCoroutine = null;
    
    [SerializeField] private float degreesToRotateBy;   // assign this variable to 90.0f in the inspector
    [SerializeField] private float timeToRotate;        // assign this variable to however much time you want the rotation to occur
    
    // axis of rotation that will occur
    private Vector3 rotationAxis = Vector3.forward;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public void Start()
    {
        rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Update()
    {
        isGroundedBlue = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(GroundCheck.position, 0.15f, groundLayerBlue);
        if (isGroundedBlue)
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.right/60;
        }
        
        isGroundedPurple = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(GroundCheck.position, 0.15f, groundLayerPurple);
        if (isGroundedPurple)
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.left / 60;
        }
    
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                jumpTimer += Time.deltaTime;
                timeCount = Time.time;
            }
            
            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                DoJump(250f * jumpTimer);
                
                jumpTimer = 0;
            }
            
            // I changed your input to GetKeyDown instead of GetKey
            // as GetKeyDown is triggered the single frame the user presses space instead of every frame
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                if (RotationCoroutine == null)
                    RotationCoroutine = StartCoroutine(RotateAxisByDegrees(degreesToRotateBy, timeToRotate, rotationAxis));
            }
    
            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                // assuming you want the rotation to stop 
                if (RotationCoroutine != null)
                    StopCoroutine(RotationCoroutine);
    
                RotationCoroutine = null;
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Rotate an object by a set angle in the rotationAxis over a set time
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="angleToRotateTo">Angle we are rotating by</param>
    /// <param name="timeToRotate">Amount of time the rotation takes</param>
    /// <param name="rotationAxis">Axis to rotate around</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private IEnumerator RotateAxisByDegrees(float angleToRotateTo, float timeToRotate, Vector3 rotationAxis)
    {
        // store our initial rotation and keep a timer for the rotation progress
        float currentTimeElapsed = 0.0f;
        Quaternion startRotation = transform.rotation;
        Quaternion endRotation = startRotation * Quaternion.AngleAxis(angleToRotateTo, rotationAxis);
    
        while (currentTimeElapsed < timeToRotate)
        {
            // set our new rotation
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(startRotation, endRotation, currentTimeElapsed / timeToRotate);
    
            // increment our timer with how long it has been since the last frame
            currentTimeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
    
            // this line will tell the coroutine to end here and continue work in the next frame
            yield return null;
        }
    
        // assign our rotation in case there are floating point errors
        transform.rotation = endRotation;
    
        // set our coroutine to null as we are done
        RotationCoroutine = null;
    }
    
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.2f, groundLayer);
    }
    
    public void DoJump(float JumpForce)
    {
        float jumpForceMagnitutde = Mathf.Clamp(JumpForce/3, 0, 50);
        rb2D.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForceMagnitutde/3, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        rb2D.AddForce(Vector2.right*jumpForceMagnitutde/10,ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to rotate this object over time or in an instant? What you have tried so far? You can use something like [`transform.Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) which would look something like `object.transform.rotate(0,0,90);`. If you want to smoothly rotate the object, you can use [`Quaternion.Slerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html) with a `from` and `to` rotation where it is your current rotation rotating towards your goal of z + 90º.

Comment: if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            
            timeCount=Time.time
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            
            
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90), timeCount*.1f);
            timeCount = 0;
}

        I made like this but its look like this https://imgur.com/397kao3

Comment: That could work if not placed inside of a conditional statement. `Lerp` works by slowly completing a process in small increments of time, generally over multiple frames. As you placed it in an `if(Input){...}`, it will only run the frame that the space key is lifted. I would save a bool to determine if the player has jumped, then allow the rotation to occur either in `Update`, or just call a `Coroutine` to have the `Lerp` run in a separate function. If you want an example I can add one.

Comment: Yes if you add one i would be pleasure thank you

Comment: Can you send me an example dude about Coroutine . I search about that but i couldn't understand how to use that in my code thank you@TEEBQNE

Comment: Just added an example. Let me know if you have questions. I added a bunch of comments and explanations with links. If you read through all of it, you should understand. I was also not 100% how you want the rotation to work, so it rotates by 90º whenever space is held, stops the rotation when it is released, and will rotate by 90º from the current point instead of to 90º, 180º, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned, the example code you posted has one main issue

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) 
{ 
    timeCount=Time.time 
} 

if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space)) 
{ 
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90), timeCount*.1f); 
    timeCount = 0; 
}
```

A [`Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) is a process that gradually completes over multiple frames. I am assuming that this input code is placed inside of the `Update` function, which normally would allow the `Lerp` to work. However, as it is inside of a conditional checking for the lifting of space, which only happens the [`single frame`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyUp.html) the user lifts a key, it will not continually run.

In situations after some sort of event (a jump in your case) occurs and I need a task gradually completed, I usually turn to [`Coroutines`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). A `Coroutine` is a function that is able to handle processes in small chunks every frame and return to where it left off in the following frame.

```
// we are going to store our coroutine to assure that it is only going to run once
private Coroutine RotationCoroutine = null;

[SerializeField] private float degreesToRotateBy;   // assign this variable to 90.0f in the inspector
[SerializeField] private float timeToRotate;        // assign this variable to however much time you want the rotation to occur

// axis of rotation that will occur
private Vector3 zRotationAxis = Vector3.forward;

private void Update()
{
    // I changed your input to GetKeyDown instead of GetKey
    // as GetKeyDown is triggered the single frame the user presses space instead of every frame
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        if (RotationCoroutine == null)
            RotationCoroutine = StartCoroutine(RotateAxisByDegrees(degreesToRotateBy, timeToRotate, zRotationAxis));
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        // assuming you want the rotation to stop 
        if (RotationCoroutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(RotationCoroutine);

        RotationCoroutine = null;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Rotate an object by a set angle in the rotationAxis over a set time
/// </summary>
/// <param name="angleToRotateTo">Angle we are rotating by</param>
/// <param name="timeToRotate">Amount of time the rotation takes</param>
/// <param name="rotationAxis">Axis to rotate around</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private IEnumerator RotateAxisByDegrees(float angleToRotateTo, float timeToRotate, Vector3 rotationAxis)
{
    // store our initial rotation and keep a timer for the rotation progress
    float currentTimeElapsed = 0.0f;
    Quaternion startRotation = transform.rotation;
    Quaternion endRotation = startRotation * Quaternion.AngleAxis(angleToRotateTo, rotationAxis);

    while (currentTimeElapsed < timeToRotate)
    {
        // set our new rotation
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(startRotation, endRotation, currentTimeElapsed / timeToRotate);

        // increment our timer with how long it has been since the last frame
        currentTimeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;

        // this line will tell the coroutine to end here and continue work in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }

    // assign our rotation in case there are floating point errors
    transform.rotation = endRotation;

    // set our coroutine to null as we are done
    RotationCoroutine = null;
}
```

I currently implemented a rotation that is done in a specific amount of time. It is possible to rotate an object given a speed instead. You can also extend the function to take in a specific axis to create a function that allows rotation on any axis by any angle in any amount of time. Just add the new parameter and do not make the axis global.

If you want to learn more about `Lerp`, there is a useful [`article`](https://gamedevbeginner.com/the-right-way-to-lerp-in-unity-with-examples/) that goes over some general practices when dealing with them.

**Edit:** To clarify why the current code is not working, it is because you are putting the if condition check for `GetKeyUp` inside of your `isGrounded` check.

```
if (isGrounded)
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        jumpTimer += Time.deltaTime;
        timeCount = Time.time;
    }
    
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        DoJump(250f * jumpTimer);
        
        jumpTimer = 0;
    }
    
    // I changed your input to GetKeyDown instead of GetKey
    // as GetKeyDown is triggered the single frame the user presses space instead of every frame
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        if (RotationCoroutine == null)
            RotationCoroutine = StartCoroutine(RotateAxisByDegrees(degreesToRotateBy, timeToRotate, rotationAxis));
    }
}

// this needs to be outside of the isGrounded
if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
{
    // assuming you want the rotation to stop 
    if (RotationCoroutine != null)
        StopCoroutine(RotationCoroutine);

    RotationCoroutine = null;
}
```

Comment: Dude thanks a lot but i have last issue when i press space it works but than i press again it doesn't and nothing happens am i doing wrong thing about that? Thank you again dude i appreciate you  A LOT

Comment: @infamora That's odd. The code should work as is. Do you have any other code influencing the presses? Did you copy the code exactly as is? What values did you assign in the inspector for the angle & time? **Edit:** Just tested it myself and seems to work.

Comment: Actually yes when press space character jumps Is that problem? Yeah i copied the code exactly.My values 90,2. How can i add my code this text i couldn't find

Comment: I'm trying to attach to empty oject and attach script to empty object

Comment: @infamora Comments are generally not meant for code unless it is `one-liners`. You can edit and add a new code block by using ```code here```.  The jump should not change how this code works unless you are altering how input works when you jump, changing rotation, or disabling the gameObject. Does it work in an empty project on a new object?

Comment: @infamora I believe the issue is you are putting the code for the reset of the rotation inside of your conditional `if(isGrounded)`. Move that code outside of the loop.

Comment: Now it works but when I press the space every 4 times the other times are just rotating 90 degrees. I understand the reason for 90 degrees but when I change it to 360 degrees nothing happens. @ TEEBQNE

Comment: @infamora Sorry can you clarify what the current issue is? I am a bit confused.

Comment: im pressing space , cube is jumping and rotating but when I press the next 3 times press the space, nothing happens. After that when press the space, cube jumping and rotating @TEEBQNE

Comment: @infamora Yea so the issue is still having the reset inside if `if(isGrounded)`. That needs to be moved out. I updated my answer to show you what I mean.